# Call Openurl in Ionic framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I want to call openurl in ionic framework in order to access itms-app://..
I have tried to use  and windows.open etc to access but all of them doesn't work.

I cannot find a plugin of the openurl function for the ionic framework.
Is there any available resources to implement this function? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-launch-external-application-with-ionic-framework/) is the complete tutorial to open external application from ionic framework.

`cordova plugin add com.lampa.startapp` plugin will help you do so.

Regards.